# Dapper Query ToList as IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> result is null

Tags: .net, linq, dapper

My Code

```
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:"))
    {
        {
            var v = connection.Query(@"select 1 A,2 B ");
            var cV = v as IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>;
            Console.WriteLine(v.GetType().FullName); // result : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow, Dapper, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
            Console.WriteLine(cV); // result : A=1,B=2
        }
        
        {

            var v = connection.Query(@"select 1 A,2 B ").ToList();
            var cV = v as IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>;
            Console.WriteLine(v.GetType().FullName); // result : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
            Console.WriteLine(cV); // result : null
        }
    }
```

My question is :
Dapper Query as `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>` `is not null`, but why after ToList then as `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>` `is null`

As I know List is extends by `IEnumerable<T>` so Dapper Query ToList Should be `IEnumerable<IDictionay<string,object>>` but result is not.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

---

update:

And It's work if specify `IDictionary<string,object>` type in foreach

```
        {
            var v = connection.Query(@"select 1 A,2 B ").ToList();
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> e in v)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.GetType().FullName); // result : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
                Console.WriteLine(e); // result : A=1,B=2           
            }
        }
```

Comment: The object inside the `List` is not a `Dictionary`, it's an anonymous object which happens to implement `IDictionary`, the `List` itself is a `List` of objects. In other words `foreach (IDictionary<string, object> e in v)` is the same as `foreach (object e in v.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>())`

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, could u answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The return type of `Query` with no generic type argument is `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, the actual object is a `List<DapperRow>`.**

`DapperRow` happens to implement `IDictionary<string, object>`. Therefore:

- In version 1 of your code you can cast the `List` directly to `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>`.
- Version 2 you are calling `ToList`, but because you haven't got the exact type, you end up with a call to `ToList<object>`. Remember, `ToList` **always** creates a new list, even when the existing object is a list already.
- Your final version goes back to the original, but now it casts each object in the list to `IDictionary<string, object>`. So it is equivalent to the following code:

```cs
foreach (var e in v.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>())
{
```

**Personally I always use actual classes with `Query<MyClass>` and I don't rely on `dynamic` or `DapperRow` as it can be inefficient and difficult to use.**